# How to nasm 32bit code on 64bit machine?

Tags: nasm

I got the following error when I try nasm with gcc (both with -m32 and without it). Does anybody know how to fix the problem? Thanks.

```
~$ cat tiny.asm 
BITS 32
GLOBAL main
SECTION .text
main:
mov eax, 42
ret
~$ nasm -f elf tiny.asm
~$ gcc -Wall -s tiny.o
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `tiny.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc -m32 -Wall -s tiny.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: add `-m32` to _GCC_ when linking.

Comment: Make sure you have the package `gcc-multilib` installed. You might also want `g++-multilib` as well.